# How to recover deleted voicemail from iPhone 4S?

Tags: iphone, voicemail

I have the iPhone 4S. This morning, I had 2 unheard voicemails. I attempted to listen to them but no sound was delivered and the progress bar did not move. A few minutes later I looked down and my messages were no longer there. Is there any way to recover these deleted voicemails?

Comment: Do any of these answers help? What outcome ever came of your deleted voicemails?

Comment: Love how you came across this a year later @bmike.

Answer (score 4):

If you did actually delete the voicemail, a new cell should have appeared if you scroll to the bottom of your voicemails.

[image: Voicemail]

Then, tap on Deleted Messages, and you should get this screen:

[image: Deleted Messages]

Now, tap on the voicemail that you would like to delete, and press Undelete:

[image: Undelete]

Hope this helps!